# Are Truffula Trees copyrighted?

Tags: logo, copyright

If I intend to use a Truffula Tree (from Dr. Seuss' The Lorax) in a logo design for a company, would that be breaking copyright laws?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal matters, not design.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on bemdesign's answer: even if it were legal you would  not want to use somebody else's concept/artwork as your logo. It would make it hard to enforce as your own trademark/brand.

Answer (score 1):

As this is a legal question and as we are **not your lawyer** and finally as the answer can vary by location (different laws) - this question is **unanswerable by us** here at StackExchange.

All this being said, if you ever find yourself asking "Is this legal?", it's usually a good sign to rethink your current design and try to come up with something better.